# Jenkins Publishing to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, jenkins, artifact-deployer

I'm working on a small project that requires the copying of a git repository of markdown files to a SharePoint directory. I'm using Jenkins for the project and now I've run into issues.

I'm new to Jenkins but I found ArtifactDeployer's post-build action and it appeared at first to be the solution. Everything works up until the point where ArtifactDeployer attempts to move the files. Here's the output:

`[ArtifactDeployer] - Starting deployment from the post-action ...
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to deploy. Can't create the directory 'https://place.net/sites/05555/otherPlace/Big Project/Development/Markdown'
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to mkdirs: https://place.net/sites/05555/otherPlace/Big Project/Development/Markdown
Build step '[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy the artifacts from build workspace to remote locations' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step '[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy the artifacts from build workspace to remote locations' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

At this point I'm thinking that ArtifactDeployer may not be the actual solution. The errors are not particularly illuminating but my guess is that it's not compatible with HTTP. The directory provided already exists, so there's no actual creation required.

Now I'm looking at alternative solutions. I'm considering emailing the files to SharePoint. Perhaps using FTP-Publisher plugin for Jenkins would work. I just want to wrap this up.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** In reviewing the email option, you can email files to the document library. There's even an option to group files into a file by the subject of the email. My testing shows that you cannot store the files two levels deep, only one. Of course my destination folder is two deep. This doesn't work for us.

New possible solution I'm looking into is mapping the address to a drive in a batch file, moving files with ArtifactDeployer, and removing the mapped drive in another, final batch file.

The newest issue is:

`System error 1244 has occurred.
The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated.`

The Jenkins user has admin rights to the SharePoint document library, it's unclear why this is happening.

**Resolution:**

I have it working now. Thanks in part to the one answer I received and some tinkering. I can confirm that your Jenkins user needs to have the proper rights level in SharePoint to complete this task. It now works with ArtifactDeployer. Here's what the meat of the Jenkins setup looks like:

Execute Windows batch command:

`net use D: "https://place.net/sites/05555/otherPlace/Big Project/Development/Markdown" password123 /User:%USERNAME%
D:`

...ArtifactDeployer does its thing...

Execute Windows batch command:

`net use D: /D`

It works!

[Snapshot of Jenkins Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQRRt.png)

Comment: Could you share more info about the environment? i.e. Your jenkins master is Linux\Windows? Is your SP accessible by HTTP only, ore other options apply as well (such as copy files to certain directory on the SP server)

Comment: Absolutely! The Jenkins master is Windows based. Our SharePoint is only accessible through HTTP, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're exceptionally close to having this solved. To be sure, check that the following are done:

1. Make sure you're including the user name and password when accessing the location.

Goes like this:

`net use Q: \\Server\files < password > /User:<username>`

Or the following if you want to use Jenkins' variables:

`net use Q: \\Server\files < password > /User:%USERNAME%`

Replace < password > with your actual password.

2. Finally, make sure that the Jenkins user has write access to the SharePoint document library. There are groups within the SharePoint system that will indicate what kind of permissions the user will have. You'll may need rights yourself to even see these lists. Just make sure those are lined up.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this as well using ArtifactDeployer.  Austin Kincaid's solution didn't work for me, but lead me to a working solution.  I mapped my sharepoint location as a drive on my build machine.  Then in my build steps, I use a batch command to copy the desired files from my Jenkins workspace to the mapped drive.